# error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, drawer

I have error in navigation drawer.My drawer on the fragment (center_fragment) is not working!!

```
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers()

            when (it.itemId) {

                R.id.contact -> findNavController().navigate(
                    centerFragmentDirections.actionCenterFragmentToContactFragment()

                )

                R.id.about_us -> findNavController().navigate(
                    centerFragmentDirections.actionCenterFragmentToAboutFragment()

                )


                else -> true
            }
```

Comment: On what line is the actual error message? Where is it happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setNavigationItemSelectedListener` expects you to return a boolean but you are not returning a boolean in 2 of your `when` branches:

```
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.contact -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(centerFragmentDirections.actionCenterFragmentToContactFragment())
                    return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.about_us -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(centerFragmentDirections.actionCenterFragmentToAboutFragment())
                    return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> true
            }
        }
```